# Where can I try minimalist running shoes?

Tags: running, running-shoes

1. What actual physical stores carry them?
2. Is there anywhere online that I could buy then return without problems if they didn't fit my foot? I have heard Zappos is good about it.

Comment: Have you tried searching for online stores first before asking your question? You should be able to easily them and see what their return policies are. For example, Zappos sells tons of shoes (I found 174 minimalist running shoes for men) and has a very generous return policy.

Comment: My runner friends swear by (and have sweet discounts for!) http://www.runningwarehouse.com/

Comment: I knew my question looked too short. I forgot to add that I did think about Zappos. Haven't heard about runningwarehouse.com though. Really wish more physical stores had them.

Comment: Other than major chain stores, have you tried searching your local business listings for physical sports sports or specialized running stores? I think you're better off with that than asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REI has Vibram Five Fingers and the Merrell Barefoot/Bareform series, if you live in the US.

I'd imagine MEC has them if you live in Canada, but I haven't been north of the border for a long time.

Elsewhere in the world I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Find a specialized shop. Online is great and all, but not for this kind of stuff.

Also at some shops you'll be able to test the shoes on a treadmill at least.

Comment: See question #1. Unfortunately, this is SD, and we are tiny. I've only found the old version of the NB ones, and the Five Fingers so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you go to a physical store to try them on before you buy. You'll end up trying on several sizes. I know for the Virbram's that you have to have an extremely precise fit or else it will rub against your foot when you where them. You want them to feel snug but not tight; if it is loose at all, try on a smaller pair.

Here in the southeast part of the US, Abbadabbas carries them. I got mine from there.